# Confirmation Modal in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that manages subscriptions.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Subscription Name</th>
      <th>Auto Renew</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-controller="SubscriptionController as subCtrl>
    <tr ng-repeat="subscription in subCtrl.subscriptions">
      <td>
      {{ subscription.name }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="autorenew onoffswitch-checkbox" id="switch-{{ subscription.id }}" value="1" ng-checked="subscription.auto_renew" switchtoggle="subCtrl.toggleAutoRenew({{subscription.id}})">
      </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

The checkbox has a directive called switchToggle.  I use this to manage the model because I need to be able to watch for the change and ask for a confirmation Modal. The Directive just runs the toggleAutoRenew function of the controller

```
/**
 *
 */
app.directive('switchtoggle', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
      element.bind('change', function(){ 
        scope.$apply(attrs.switchtoggle);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

What I haven't been able to figure out what to do is create a modal with confirm and cancel buttons.  That way when someone clicks on the checkbox (which looks like an on off switch) I can confirm whether they really want it on or off.

help please....

Comment: Do you use a certain library and want to know how to open a confirmation dialog? Or do you want to know how to call the built-in function `confirm`? Or is it something else you want to know?

Comment: I do not use a certain library.  I want to know how to do it.  I want to know 1) open on change 2) then read when a confirm or cancel has been selected.

Comment: Still not clear. But you can do `var ok = confirm('please confirm you choice');` if that suits your need.

Comment: I do NOT want to use a javascript confirm.  I want to open a modal box that can be styled that has 2 buttons on it.  The buttons need to talk back to the controller scope telling me if they confirmed or cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'd like to also suggest using [UI Bootstrap's Modal Dialog](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), but read the full answer before you string me up :)

First, here is a [demo of your ***EXACT*** scenario](http://plnkr.co/edit/quLrDSzOLWH0OB8eKcdj?p=preview).

Now let me walk through the code.

The only change I made to your markup was to drop the custom directive in favor of a simple `ng-click` handler.

```
ng-click="subCtrl.toggleAutoRenew($event, subscription)
```

Notice the `$event` I am passing in there, that is important because it allows us to be able to call `.preventDefault()`, which will stop the model from being updated, and give us a chance to show a confirmation dialog to the user.

The toggle method passes in the entire subscription object, and then simply cancels further event processing.

```
toggleAutoRenew: function($event, subscription) {
      var _this = this;

      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

      _this.confirmAutoRenew(subscription)
        .then(function() {
          subscription.auto_renew = !subscription.auto_renew;
        });
    }
```

We then make a call to another method responsible for showing the dialog that returns a `promise`.

**If the promise is resolved**, then we toggle the `auto_renew` flag on the `subscription` object and everything works as expected.

**If the promise is rejected**, then we do nothing, and the subscription is never updated. To the user, it's as though they never clicked the checkbox at all.

You can look at the example to see how that method is making use of UI Bootstrap and the `$modal` service to show a dialog and handle the result, but the *logic* is all inside the toggle method, and it's **100% handled by the controller**.

Comment: I don't string people up who actually explain code.  I only string them up if they throw links at me with no explanations.  I'll give this a try when I start my work day in a few hours and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Since I am using bootstrap and the example code you provided helped me do what I needed to get done I gave you the answer checkmark.  I would really love to understand how to do this without bootstrap and without bootstrap-ui.  Actually knowing how it works in the background (ie the $modal state) would be useful.  I'll have to sort that out later I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can see how to open modals:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Btw, here is how your input should look like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="autorenew onoffswitch-checkbox" ng-model="subscription.auto_renew" ng-change="subCtrl.toggleAutoRenew(subscription)">
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question please don't throw un-useful answers that do NOT answer the question.  ng-change or change binding in an directive do the same thing.

Comment: Documentation and examples on modals do not answer question about opening modals? ok.

Comment: Opening the Modal is NOT the problem. Connecting back to the controller with the "confirm" and "cancel" button is the problem.  therefore this was not helpful.

Comment: from  http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/: $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  }; But as I see for you Ok/Cancel buttons wont fit - u need Confirm.

Comment: No it doesn't because that $scope belongs to ModalController  and NOT to SubscriptionController.  This creates a whole new controller that is outside the realm of the controller I am working in.  I need to talk back to the SubscriptionController.  I spent ALL day looking at THIS exact code.  It does not answer my question.